# How to remove bootstrap breadcrumbs outline border color?

Tags: html, css

I tried many ways to remove breadcrumbs outline border but failed. Can anyone solve this issue?

Html Code

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <div class="toggler-btn">
          <div class="bar bar1"></div>
          <div class="bar bar2"></div>
          <div class="bar bar3"></div>
        </div>
      </button>
```

css code

```
.toggler-btn:focus{
  outline: 0!important;
}
```

[image: Here is snapshot of the breadcrumbs border outline]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
.navbar-toggler:focus,
.navbar-toggler:active,
.navbar-toggler-icon:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: Oh great, all magic was on **.navbar-toggler:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
}**. Thanks for your response, mate!